# TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: float, integer, typeerror

Al pedir un dato por consola de tipo float, ya que debe permitir la opción de ingresar decimales, dentro de la función que estoy realizando necesito convertir los vectores de las variables que uso a 0. Es ahí donde rebota en un error.

```
#Datos que necesito para operar el metodo de Euler
h = float(input("Tamaño de paso: "))
s = float(input("Valor maximo deseado: "))
n = (s/h)+1

#Se llenan los dos vectores de 0 para iniciar el conteo
x = np.zeros(n)
y = np.zeros(n)
```

Comment: Y que error aparece?

Answer (score 0):

La razón por la que te encuentras recibiendo aquel error es debido a que la función `np.zero` solo recibe valores del tipo *float*, y el inconveniente se da en al inicalizar la variable `n`: Al realizar la división, sin importar si el resultado de esta es un número entero o no, python lo guarda como un *float*, ocasionando que este valor no pueda ser usado por función `np.zero` ya que solo recibe valores del tipo *integer*.

La manera de solucionar tu problema es la sigueinte:

```
#Datos que necesito para operar el metodo de Euler
h = float(input("Tamaño de paso: "))
s = float(input("Valor maximo deseado: "))
n = int((s/h)+1) #Cambio presentado

#Se llenan los dos vectores de 0 para iniciar el conteo
x = np.zeros(n)
y = np.zeros(n)
```

La función `int` se encarga de convertir el valor resultante a un *Integer*, haciendo que pueda ser usada sin problema alguno.